# Meaning of statsmodels OLS return.params

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to do linear regression with OLS and `Res.params` has retruned me a 2x2 array. 
I know the `.params[0][1]` and `.params[1][1]` are the beta and constant of the regression. However, what's the meaning for `.params[0][0]` and `.params[1][0]` ?

My implementation:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = np.arange(0, 20)
X = sm.add_constant(X)
Y = (X * 3) + 8
Res = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
Res.params
array([[  1.10000000e+01,   8.00000000e+00],
       [  5.37764278e-17,   3.00000000e+00]])
```

Questions:

1. What is the meaning of those values?
2. How can I change my implementation, so it can return the array with beta and constant only?

Comment: It seems to me that `Y = (X * 3) + 8` line should go before adding the constant. Your dependent variable is a two-dimensional array now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @user2285236. It seems I messed up the order of the implementation. It works now:)

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = np.arange(0, 20)
Y = (X * 3) + 8
X = sm.add_constant(X)
Res = sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
Res.params
array([ 8.,  3.])
```